# Marionette.js - can I detect onAppend?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I have a silly problem, where my only solution is a sloppy hack that is now giving me other problems.

[See my fiddle,](http://jsfiddle.net/rNBEC/2/)

or read the code here:

#### HTML:

```
<input id='1' value='input1' />
<template id='template1'>
    <input id='2' value='input2' />
</template>
```

#### JS - Item View Declaration:

```
// Declare an ItemView, a simple input template.
var Input2 = Marionette.ItemView.extend({

    template: '#template1',
    onRender: function () {
        console.log('hi');
    },

    ui: { input2: '#2' },

    onRender: function () {

        var self = this;

        // Despite not being in the DOM yet, you can reference
        // the input, through the 'this' command, as the
        // input is a logical child of the ItemView.
        this.ui.input2.val('this works');

        // However, you can not call focus(), as it 
        // must be part of the DOM.
        this.ui.input2.focus();

        // So, I have had to resort to this hack, which 
        // TOTALLY SUCKS.

        setTimeout(function(){
          self.ui.input2.focus();
          self.ui.input2.val('Now it focused. Dammit');  
        }, 1000)
    },

})
```

#### JS - Controller

```
// To start, we focus input 1. This works.
$('#1').focus();

// Now, we make input 2.
var input2 = new Input2();

// Now we 1. render, (2. onRender is called), 3. append it to the DOM.
$(document.body).append(input2.render().el);
```

As one can see above, my problem is that I can not make a View call focus on itself after it is rendered (`onRender`), as it has not yet been appended to the DOM. As far as I know, there is no other event called such as `onAppend`, that would let me detect when it has actually been appended to the DOM.

I don't want to call focus from outside of the ItemView. It has to be done from within for my purposes.

Any bright ideas?

#### UPDATE

Turns out that `onShow()` is called on all DOM appends in Marionette.js, be it CollectionView, CompositeView or Region, and it *isn't in the documentation!*

Thanks a million, lukaszfiszer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to render your `ItemView` inside a `Marionette.Region`. This way an `onShow` method will be called on the view once it's inserted in the DOM.

Example:

### HTML

```
<input id='1' value='input1' />
<div id="inputRegion"></div>
<template id='template1'>
  <input id='2' value='input2' />
</template>
```

### JS ItemView

```
(...)

onShow: function () {
    this.ui.input2.val('this works');
    this.ui.input2.focus();
},

(...)
```

### JS Controller

```
$('#1').focus();

var inputRegion = new Backbone.Marionette.Region({
  el: "#inputRegion"
});

var input2 = new Input2();

inputRegion.show(input2);
```

More information in Marionette docs: https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.region.md#region-events-and-callbacks

Comment: Thanks - see that's the exact type of thing I was looking for. Too bad it only works for regions, though, which I just think is a sloppy design in Marionette.js. Check out my answer to my question I just worked out - do you consider this a good idea.?

Comment: Looking at the source code (https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/src/marionette.collectionview.js#L159) it seems that `onShow` is called also on views inside CollecitonView, although it's not documented.

Comment: You're badass. That totally answers my question! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I managed to solve it by extending Marionette.js, but if anyone else has a better idea that doesn't involve extending a library, I will *GLADLY* accept it and buy you a doughnut.

```
// After studying Marionette.js' annotated source code,
// I found these three functions are the only places
// where a view is appended after rendering. Extending
// these by adding an onAppend call to the end of
// each lets me focus and do other DOM manipulation in
// the ItemView or Region, once I am certain it is in
// the DOM.

_.extend(Marionette.CollectionView.prototype, {
  appendHtml: function(collectionView, itemView, index){
    collectionView.$el.append(itemView.el);
    if (itemView.onAppend) { itemView.onAppend() }
  },
});

_.extend(Marionette.CompositeView.prototype, {
  appendHtml: function(cv, iv, index){
    var $container = this.getItemViewContainer(cv);
    $container.append(iv.el);
    if (itemView.onAppend) { itemView.onAppend() }
  },  
});

_.extend(Marionette.Region.prototype, {
 open: function(view){
    this.$el.empty().append(view.el);
    if (view.onAppend) { view.onAppend() }
  },  
});
```